# Как присвоить строке значение

Tags: c++

Как присвоить строке типа string значение 2 символов типа char (элементов массива)?

```
string arr [ 10 ]; // к примеру заполнены символами
string c = arr [ 1 ] + arr [ 2 ]; // так выдает ошибку
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что `arr[10]` - это массив строк, а не символов? Какую именно ошибку вам выдают? (научитесь читать и понимать сообщения об ошибках!)

Comment: Я понимаю это прекрасно, но когда в строку записываешь 1 символ от считается как char.

Answer (score 3):

Путём пыток и телепатии выяснено, что на самом деле вопрос должен звучать так:

> Почему не работает код **`std::string c = 'c'`**?

Ответ: потому что оператора присвоения строке значения символа не существует. В самом грубом приближении можно сделать так:

```
std::string c;
c.push_back( arr[1][1] );
c.push_back( arr[2][1] );
```

(надеюсь, единицы в индексах - это не ошибка и все понимают, что индексы здесь 0-based).

Ну а для подробностей - таки [читать документацию](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). Желательно **до** того, как писать код, и перед тем, как задавать вопросы :)

Comment: std::string arr[10];
    arr[1] = "123";
    arr[2] = "abc";
    std::string c = arr[1][1] + arr[2][1];
    std::cout << c << '\n'; Вот такой не работает.

Comment: Продолжаем вытягивать информацию под пытками: а вы читали что пишет вам компилятор? Поняли? Что он скажет вам на такое: `std::string c = 'a'`?

Answer (score 1):

> std::string arr[10]; arr[1] = "123"; arr[2] = "abc"; std::string c =
>   arr[1][1] + arr[2][1]; std::cout << c << '\n'; Вот такой не работает.

Можешь добавлять отдельные символы к строке через push_back:

```
std::string arr[10]; arr[1] = "123"; arr[2] = "abc";     
std::string c; 
c.push_back(arr[1][1]); 
c.push_back(arr[2][1]); 
std::cout << c << '\n';
```

Result:

```
2b
```